# No manual entry for man

Tags: centos, man, docker

I'm working in a [Centos 6.6 Docker image](https://github.com/CentOS/sig-cloud-instance-images/blob/72a13cc9b85c6c500531d5f1e1dd86b8308a1cda/docker/Dockerfile).  I thought I installed everything to get access to man pages, but apparently not...

```
$ yum install -y man man-pages man-pages-overrides
[...]
Complete!
$ which man
/usr/bin/man
$ man man
No manual entry for man
```

What am I missing ?

---

Regarding questions in comments (thanks for your help everyone):

```
$ echo $MANPATH
# empty
$ man 1 man
No entry for man in section 1 of the manual
$ man 7 man
No entry for man in section 7 of the manual
$ ll /usr/share/man/man1/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep 23  2011 ./
drwxr-xr-x 61 root root 4096 Jan 31 01:55 ../
$ yum search man | grep db
ModemManager.x86_64 : Mobile broadband modem management service
hsqldb-manual.noarch : Manual for hsqldb
db4-utils.x86_64 : Command line tools for managing Berkeley DB (version 4)
foomatic-db-ppds.noarch : PPDs from printer manufacturers
ldb-tools.x86_64 : Tools to manage LDB files

$ rpm -q -l man | grep man.1
/usr/share/doc/man-1.6f
/usr/share/doc/man-1.6f/COPYING
/usr/share/doc/man-1.6f/README
/usr/share/man/bg/man1/man.1.gz
/usr/share/man/cs/man1/man.1.gz
/usr/share/man/da/man1/man.1.gz
/usr/share/man/de/man1/man.1.gz
/usr/share/man/el/man1/man.1.gz
/usr/share/man/en/man1/man.1.gz
/usr/share/man/es/man1/man.1.gz
/usr/share/man/fi/man1/man.1.gz
/usr/share/man/fr/man1/man.1.gz
/usr/share/man/hr/man1/man.1.gz
/usr/share/man/it/man1/man.1.gz
/usr/share/man/ja/man1/man.1.gz
/usr/share/man/ko/man1/man.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/man.1.gz
/usr/share/man/nl/man1/man.1.gz
/usr/share/man/pl/man1/man.1.gz
/usr/share/man/pt/man1/man.1.gz
/usr/share/man/ro/man1/man.1.gz
/usr/share/man/sl/man1/man.1.gz
```

Comment: Isn't `MANPATH` environment variable overriden? Also, try this: `man -M /usr/share/man man`

Comment: What are the results of `man 1 man` and `man 7 man`, please?

Comment: Debian has a package called `man-db`. Of course, CentOS may be set up differently.

Comment: Do you have the file `/usr/share/man/man1/man.1.gz` ?

Comment: Thanks everyone, I answered directly in the question for readabily sake.

Comment: The `man` package ought to include it. Does `rpm -q -l man | grep man.1` show anything?

Comment: Yep, there's some output.  I put it in the question.

Comment: It's strange that rpm claims there's a `/usr/share/man/man1/man.1.gz` installed, but your `ls /usr/share/man/man1/` shows an empty directory.

Comment: Yeah I'm completely lost.  Actually if I run `tree` in `/usr/share/man/`, `man8` is the only directory containing something.  And its 4 symlinks named `iptable-<topic>.8.gz` pointing to `/etc/alternatives/man-iptables-<topic>.x86_64`...

Comment: I have the same problem, no solution yet. Turns out that yum doesn't invoke rpm, instead it directly uses rpmlib (through python bindings). So their behavior is not identical because they likely use rpmlib in different ways.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the comment re: removing `tsflags=nodocs` from `/etc/yum.conf`, put there as a purported consequence of base docker image build policy:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/docker-user/fuW0e9xlqQE

I just tested this on a CentOS 6.7 container and it works.

Comment: Thank you for this; I got man and man pages installed. But for some bizarre reason there's nothing in section 8. Still haven't figured that one out!

Comment: works for CentOS 7

Answer (score 0):

If `echo $MANPATH` is empty you need to set the manpath.

`echo "MANPATH=/usr/share/man" >> ~/.bashrc`

The login again.

Comment: I am using Debian 9. $MANPATH is empty and man works.

Comment: @Debian_yadav+ ditto on CentOS 6.7 (though not docker), and every other implementation of `man` I've ever used.